# Mixing jQuery and php failing caused by noConflict (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to mix jQuery and php in wordpress.

This is my current code:

```
function theme_output($url) {
echo "<script language='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(function($) {
        var $products,
        $current_product = 'default';

        // List all the products here

        $products = {
    ";
        $themes = array('cerulean', 'cosmo', 'cyborg', 'darkly', 'flatly', 'journal', 'lumen', 'paper', 'readable', 'sandstone', 'simplex', 'slate', 'spacelab', 'superhero', 'united', 'yeti');
        foreach ($themes as $theme) {
            echo 
                $theme." : {
                    name     : '".ucfirst($theme)."',
                    tag      : 'phpBB',
                    img      : '".css_file($theme)."',
                    url      : '".$url."?theme=".$theme."',
                    purchase : 'http://www.google.de',
                },";
        };
echo "
    };
});
    </script>";
};
```

So there is a "header" in jquery/javascript and then a foreach php part and at least a jquery "footer" part.

The problem is, that the wordpress no conflict (I guess this is the reason), deletes all the $variables.

This is the output:
[image]

Can somebody help me to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: var $products?  Is $products a js or php variable?

Comment: Dave: But I have to differ the quotes " that tell php the beginning and the end of a echo and the quotes ' that are used for jquery
@nemmy: js

Comment: @nemmy: its a js variable

Comment: it might need encoding so try enclosing  it in forward slashes  \'\default\'\

Comment: Is the JS being injected into the header of the page or the footer?

Comment: PHP will try to evalute `$products` as a variable that hasn't any value I suppose. So you need to escape the `$` so that PHP ignores it... do it like this `\$products`.

Comment: you can figure this out on your own....write out the javascript you want, enclose with single quotes and use "." to concenate strings. Btw never set vars in js with $ if you are using this as the symbol in jQuery, it translates to jQuery(var). have another go and post if you are having probs.

Comment: Or use `?> ... <?php`, there's a few ways but they all require some modification of your code on your part.

Comment: @David: I searched a lot and can only find, that I can replace the $ in front of every function with jQuery. But with variables, this does not work. Can you give me a link, where this is explained?

Comment: no, but i can explain with 1 line, php uses '$' symbol for variables js does not, you can leave out the '$' as its treated like text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to solve the problem is, to put the foreach part into a own function.
You should also change the " and the '.

Like this:

```
function theme_output($url) {
echo '
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var $products,
            $current_product = "default";

            // List all the products here

            $products = {
';

funct2($url);

echo '
            };
    </script>';
};

function func2($url) {
    $themes = array('cerulean', 'cosmo', 'cyborg', 'darkly', 'flatly', 'journal', 'lumen', 'paper', 'readable', 'sandstone', 'simplex', 'slate', 'spacelab', 'superhero', 'united', 'yeti');
    foreach ($themes as $theme) {
        echo $theme.' : {
                name     : "'.ucfirst($theme).'",
                tag      : "phpBB",
                img      : "'.css_file($theme).'",
                url      : "'.$url.'?theme='.$theme.'",
                purchase : "http://www.google.de",
            },

        ';
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses jQuery instead of $

Try to replace all the $ with the word jQuery

Comment: But when I do this for variables, a var like $products would become jQueryproducts and thats not right...